# I'm getting and excess elements in scalar initializer

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to declare an array 4x4 which will hold x,y and z coordinates for my graphics program. but I am getting an error " excess elements in scalar initialization". could someone tell me where I am going wrong.

The code for the array is mentioned below.

```
float controls[4][4] = {
{
    { 10,0,10 },
    {  5,0,10 },
    { -5,0,10 },
    {-10,0,10 }
},
{
    { 10,0,5 },
    {  5,6,5 },
    { -5,6,5 },
    {-10,0,5 }
},
{
    { 10,0,-5 },
    {  5,6,-5 },
    { -5,6,-5 },
    {-10,0,-5 }
},
{
    { 10,0,-10 },
    {  5,0,-10 },
    { -5,0,-10 },
    {-10,0,-10 }
}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a 3D array. Try this instead:

```
float controls[4][4][3] = ...
```

Example for a 2D array would be:

```
float one_control[4][3] =
{
    { 10,0,10 },
    {  5,0,10 },
    { -5,0,10 },
    {-10,0,10 }
} ;
```

You have four of those.